# gcc assembler - create only the minimal instructions necessary

Tags: gcc, assembly, embedded, machine-code

I have created a very minimal application in assembly. It sets some registers to 0 and does a multiplication. Nothing fancy.

However, the gcc adds a lot of stuff to the machine code I do not want.

A small list of the stuff I find in the objdump:

- deregister_tm_clones
- register_tm_clones
- __do_global_dtors_aux
- frame_dummy
- __libc_fini_array
- memset
- and a few more

I know that I do not need them, but I have no idea how I can tell to compiler to stop including them. I tried to use optimization options, but this did not change anything.

I compile it basically like: GCC -o ./main.elf ./main.S

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: If your only reason for using the gcc driver is to pre-process the assembly code, you can just run the preprocessor (cpp) on its own, followed by gas and ld to assemble and link.

Answer (score 3):

GCC automatically links the C / C++ runtime start-up crt0.o and the standard library.  You can provide your own startup code to override the default and provide command line options to force it not to link no the standard library.

Options controlling startup and default libraries include:

```
-nostartfiles
-nostdlib
-nodefaultlubs
-nolibc
```

Each affects the link in a different way, but in this case `-nostdlib` will exclude both crt0.o and standard libraries.  Of course if your code makes no reference to the standard library then nothing will be linked in any case, but explicitly excluding it will helpfully generate a link error if something does reference it.

See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Be aware that if your code does not establish a valid C runtime environment, providing for example static initialisation and a stack (a minimum), then some C code may not run in the manner intended.  You may also need to specify the entry point via `--entry=entry` if you do not use the same default entry point as crt0 (`_start` I think).

Alternatively you can invoke gcc with the `-c` option and separately invoke the linker ld without specifying any library.

Comment: Yes, you write a `_start` instead of a `main` if you want to skip CRT startup.  `_start` isn't a function, you can't `ret` from it, only make an `_exit` or `exit_group` system call.

Comment: @PeterCordes That is not what I intended.  I assumed it defined the direct entry point rather than the C entry point. I stand corrected.  I guess then it has no effect if the crt0 replacement does not reference it?  It was just a minor note, and perhaps not the issue I thought.

Comment: Oh, the kernel still sets up a stack before running userspace.  Consult the ABI docs for the initial process state, instead of the function-call state that you get at the top of main.  But using `--entry=main` will make your code segfault if it tries to return from main.  Also, on some systems (e.g. Linux), dynamic linking can let libc initialize itself even if CRT startup didn't run its init functions, but statically linking libc into a static executable will leave many functions (like stdio and `exit`) broken, except for system call wrappers that don't need any data like `_exit`.

Comment: Anyway, yeah you normally don't want to use `--entry`, just call your entry point `_start` if you're writing the ELF entry point.  `ld` looks for that as the entry point by default.  CRT0 provides a `_start` (which eventually calls `main`) but yeah if you want to leave out CRT you have to write your own.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am an embedded systems developer, every gcc toolchain I have ever used has been for standalone environments, so crt0 creates the stack.  It is not specified what environment this relates to, but most likely you are correct.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  Mainstream OSes like Linux and Windows create new processes with a stack already mapped.  (For Linux, the x86-64 System V ABI specifies that the stack pointer initially points to `argc`, with `argv[]` (the array of pointers itself) right above it.  So a minimal `_start` could be something like `pop rdi` (argc) / `mov rsi, rsp` (char **argv) / `lea rdx, [rsp + rdi*8 + 8]` (envp) / `call main` if I have the offset right for envp after argv.

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually I take that back, this is more likely a standalone system given the embedded tag.  Forgot we were on that, when you mentioned kernel established environment.  In ARM Cortex M it is in fact possible to write startup code in C (if you don't rely on static init) run directly from the reset vector since the initial stack pointer value is included in the vector table. But I digress.

Comment: I have used the -c option and that did the trick. thank you very much!

Comment: @jaskdjfasdhfawlg It is not at all clear from your question that you had not intended to link the code.  If you have more than one object module, you will have no choice.  Then the linker option will be required.

Answer (score 2):

so.S:

```
nop
nop
```

then build.

```
as so.S -o so.o
ld -Ttext=0x1000 so.o -o so.elf
objdump -D so.elf

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000001000 <__bss_start-0x200002>:
    1000:   90                      nop
    1001:   90                      nop

objcopy -O binary so.elf so.bin
hexdump -C so.bin
00000000  90 90                                             |..|
00000002
```

using gcc

```
gcc -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -ffreestanding so.S -Xlinker "-Ttext=0x1000" -o so.elf
```

this leaves extra garbage in the file, but

```
gcc so.S -c -o so.o
ld -Ttext=0x2000 so.o -o so.elf
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000002000
objdump -D so.elf


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000002000 <__bss_start-0x200002>:
    2000:   90                      nop
    2001:   90                      nop
```

But if writing assembly language you might as well use the assembler not the compiler.

_start is not required unless you need an entry point defined in the file then you need to do this:

```
.globl _start
_start:
```

plus possibly something in the linker to call that out as the entry point for file formats like elf, exe, etc.

works for cross compiling as well

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x3000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000003000
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00003000 <__bss_end__-0x10008>:
    3000:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)
    3004:   e1a00000    nop         ; (mov r0, r0)


pdp11-aout-as so.s -o so.elf
pdp11-aout-as so.s -o so.o
pdp11-aout-ld -Ttext=0x400 so.o -o so.elf
pdp11-aout-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format a.out-pdp11


Disassembly of section .text:

00000400 <so.o>:
 400:   00a0            nop
 402:   00a0            nop
```

and so on.

Comment: yes I never do the gcc thing so I started with so.s then copied to so.S so some of the command lines used one file others used the other.